# Series of consecutive numbers And Its reverse are multiplied to create series .Find Its formula.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a Series of Number from 0 to N

S = 0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ..... upto N

There is another series S2 which is nothing but S reversed.

S2 = N + (N-1) + (N-2) + (N-3) + ..... upto 0

corresponding  term's of both are multiplied:

N.0  + (N-1).1 + (N-2).2 + (N-3).3 + ....

It can be generalized as :
 ∑ i*(N-i)  where  i= 0 to N

Is there any general formula for this summation like we have sum of first N terms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{i=0}^Ni(N-i)=N \sum_{i=0}^N i-\sum_{i=0}^Ni^2=N \times \frac{1}{2} N (N+1)-\frac{1}{6} N (N+1) (2 N+1)$$